# Exception when connecting Spring Security SAML sample app to ADFS 3.0 Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-saml, adfs3.0

I've been trying to reconfigure the sample application that comes with the Spring Security SAML extension to talk to our ADFS 3.0 server instead of the SSOCircle example. After following the instructions in the Spring documentation I can now authenticate with ADFS and 'SUCCESS' is passed back to the sample app.

However, each time we get the following worrying-looking message in the Tomcat log:

```
- AuthNRequest;SUCCESS;127.0.0.1;urn:test:adfstest:gb;http://vADFS.adfstest.local/adfs/services/trust;org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f: Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN;;
- SAML protocol message was not signed, skipping XML signature processing
java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big.
        at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getLength(DerInputStream.java:561)
        at sun.security.util.DerValue.init(DerValue.java:365)
        at sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:320)
        at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1914)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.KeyStoreBuilder.tryJKS(KeyStoreBuilder.java:450)
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.KeyStoreBuilder.parse(KeyStoreBuilder.java:416)
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<init>(TrustMaterial.java:207)
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<init>(TrustMaterial.java:160)
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<init>(TrustMaterial.java:165)
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<init>(TrustMaterial.java:170)
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<clinit>(TrustMaterial.java:92)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.X509Util.decodeCertificate(X509Util.java:351)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.KeyInfoHelper.getCertificate(KeyInfoHelper.java:201)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.KeyInfoHelper.getCertificates(KeyInfoHelper.java:176)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.provider.InlineX509DataProvider.extractCertificates(InlineX509DataProvider.java:192)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.provider.InlineX509DataProvider.process(InlineX509DataProvider.java:126)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.processKeyInfoChild(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:300)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.processKeyInfoChildren(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:256)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.processKeyInfo(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:190)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.resolveFromSource(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:149)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:57)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:37)
        at org.opensaml.security.MetadataCredentialResolver.retrieveFromMetadata(MetadataCredentialResolver.java:275)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.trust.MetadataCredentialResolver.retrieveFromMetadata(MetadataCredentialResolver.java:123)
        at org.opensaml.security.MetadataCredentialResolver.resolveFromSource(MetadataCredentialResolver.java:178)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:57)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:37)
        at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.validate(ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.java:98)
        at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.validate(ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.java:49)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.AbstractProfileBase.verifySignature(AbstractProfileBase.java:267)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertionSignature(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:419)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertion(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:292)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:214)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:82)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big.
        at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getLength(DerInputStream.java:561)
        at sun.security.util.DerValue.init(DerValue.java:365)
        at sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:320)
        at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1914)
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.KeyStoreBuilder.tryJKS(KeyStoreBuilder.java:450)
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.KeyStoreBuilder.parse(KeyStoreBuilder.java:416)
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<init>(TrustMaterial.java:207)
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<init>(TrustMaterial.java:160)
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<init>(TrustMaterial.java:165)
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<init>(TrustMaterial.java:170)
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<clinit>(TrustMaterial.java:92)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.X509Util.decodeCertificate(X509Util.java:351)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.KeyInfoHelper.getCertificate(KeyInfoHelper.java:201)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.KeyInfoHelper.getCertificates(KeyInfoHelper.java:176)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.provider.InlineX509DataProvider.extractCertificates(InlineX509DataProvider.java:192)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.provider.InlineX509DataProvider.process(InlineX509DataProvider.java:126)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.processKeyInfoChild(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:300)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.processKeyInfoChildren(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:256)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.processKeyInfo(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:190)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.resolveFromSource(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:149)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:57)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:37)
        at org.opensaml.security.MetadataCredentialResolver.retrieveFromMetadata(MetadataCredentialResolver.java:275)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.trust.MetadataCredentialResolver.retrieveFromMetadata(MetadataCredentialResolver.java:123)
        at org.opensaml.security.MetadataCredentialResolver.resolveFromSource(MetadataCredentialResolver.java:178)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:57)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:37)
        at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.validate(ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.java:98)
        at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.validate(ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.java:49)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.AbstractProfileBase.verifySignature(AbstractProfileBase.java:267)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertionSignature(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:419)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertion(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:292)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:214)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:82)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.security.KeyStoreException: failed to extract any certificates or private keys - maybe bad password?
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.KeyStoreBuilder.parse(KeyStoreBuilder.java:436)
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<init>(TrustMaterial.java:207)
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<init>(TrustMaterial.java:160)
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<init>(TrustMaterial.java:165)
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<init>(TrustMaterial.java:170)
        at org.apache.commons.ssl.TrustMaterial.<clinit>(TrustMaterial.java:92)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.x509.X509Util.decodeCertificate(X509Util.java:351)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.KeyInfoHelper.getCertificate(KeyInfoHelper.java:201)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.KeyInfoHelper.getCertificates(KeyInfoHelper.java:176)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.provider.InlineX509DataProvider.extractCertificates(InlineX509DataProvider.java:192)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.provider.InlineX509DataProvider.process(InlineX509DataProvider.java:126)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.processKeyInfoChild(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:300)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.processKeyInfoChildren(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:256)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.processKeyInfo(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:190)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.keyinfo.BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.resolveFromSource(BasicProviderKeyInfoCredentialResolver.java:149)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:57)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:37)
        at org.opensaml.security.MetadataCredentialResolver.retrieveFromMetadata(MetadataCredentialResolver.java:275)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.trust.MetadataCredentialResolver.retrieveFromMetadata(MetadataCredentialResolver.java:123)
        at org.opensaml.security.MetadataCredentialResolver.resolveFromSource(MetadataCredentialResolver.java:178)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:57)
        at org.opensaml.xml.security.credential.AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.resolve(AbstractCriteriaFilteringCredentialResolver.java:37)
        at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.validate(ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.java:98)
        at org.opensaml.xml.signature.impl.ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.validate(ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine.java:49)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.AbstractProfileBase.verifySignature(AbstractProfileBase.java:267)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertionSignature(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:419)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertion(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:292)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:214)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:82)
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter.doFilter(MetadataGeneratorFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It seems to be having trouble interpreting a certificate, but I don't know which one. I'm surmising it's something specific to the ADFS setup as the same sample app works without error when connecting to  SSOCircle.

I have tried to Google what this means and how to resolve it but haven't managed to find a clear answer. Does anyone recognise this error and can give me a push in the right direction? I'm pretty green on Spring/SAML and have no ADFS experience so I'm struggling to even find the right questions to ask.

Many thanks.